# Java - Unable to find a file path which certainly exists

Tags: java, windows, file, exception

I am sure this is a relatively simple question, and I actually think it may be more of a problem with Windows than with Java.

I have a method for copying a file to a new directory, which takes two File objects, a File created with the path of the original, and a File created with the desired path of the copy. I am sure that the method works because I have used it to successfully copy a file onto my Desktop.

However, using my actual desired path creates an error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: *PATH* (The system cannot find the path
>   specified)

Where the *`PATH`* is the path that I am attempting to use.

Here is my guess:
I am making this program for use on another machine. As such, the path that I am trying to use is:

> C:\Users\XXXXXX\rest_of_path\filename.file

where `XXXXXX` is the primary user on the machine which I am writing the program for.

This directory exists on my system, but `XXXXXX` is not a user on my system. So I am guessing that Windows is causing a problem because of that.

I'm now changing my code to use a solution which depends on the machine, and is not hardcoded (System.getProperty).

However, I'd really like to know why this problem is occurring, from an academic standpoint, as a Windows and Java user.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** accidentally used forward slashes when I meant double backslashes. To ensure that it was not a spelling error, I simply copied the directory using windows, and pasted it into my program (then doubled up on the backslashes).

**EDIT:** several users have suggested something which is far more clean than what I am trying to do in the first place. I'm leaving this question open because I'm curious why it is not working.

**EDIT:** I used the solution above and I'm completely happy with it. I still don't know why Windows will not allow me to access the original path, but I guess I really don't care at this point. Thanks, everybody!

Comment: In your code, are you using forward slashes, as shown in your text above? If you're using backslashes, you'll have to double them -- e.g., "C:\\Users\\XXXXXXX\\rest_of_path\\filename.file" .

Comment: If you are using forward slashes, paste the relevant code.

Comment: @AndyThomas Instead of using \\, would it not be better to use File.pathSeparator?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it. I was, and am using double backslashes but I am more used to web addresses so I wrote the forward slash in the question.

Comment: You *should* use forward slashes: they work everywhere and don't have to be doubled in source code. Which path doesn't exist? You say that xxxx exists under Users but you don't have a user with that name, how is that possible?

Comment: I'm confused... you're getting a FileNotFoundException--is this for the file you're copying *to*?  If so, then it would be expected that the file wouldn't yet exist (but the folder that will contain the file should exist already).  Is the exception occurring when using a method that *does* expect the file to already exist?  I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: 1. Even if you are on Windows, in Java ALWAYS use FORWARD slashes in file-paths -- java will take care of the conversion, anyhow. Makes life easier :) 2. Usually, much better to use System.getProperty("user.home") to find the home directory, then you dont have to hardcode it.

Comment: @Joni That is good to know, and it worked for my test case (copying to Desktop) but did not solve my problem. As for the second question, XXXXXX exists under Users because I created a new folder there, named XXXXXX. However, that folder does not correspond to an actual user, it's just a dummy.

Comment: @ajb: That is correct. I didn't write the method for copying the files, but it's a stream operation, and does not produce an exception when I copy the file to my desktop, even if the file does not previously exist

Comment: @Rop Thank you so much for #2, that will solve my problem quite nicely. I'm still interested from an academic standpoint why Windows won't let me do this, but I'm probably going to use your solution either way.

Comment: Reason might well be: you made some little typo somewhere with all those backslashes -- happens all the time! Doublecheck it :)

Comment: Also, do a System.out.println(...) on the filepath you are trying to write to -- think that will solve your mystery...

Comment: @Rop That was the first thing that I tried. I compared the path that Java saw (System.out.println) with the path that Windows saw (using explorer to copy a file directory) and they are the same. I'll do it one more time to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

In java, and generally most programming languages, you don't always have to provide the exact directory of your file. Although it would be nice to see the code you're using to get the file, I'll provide how it can be done.

I'm assuming you aren't using `new File("file.txt")` because that retrieves files from the folder your program is in, and doesn't require an entire address like `C:\...\...\...`. You certainly don't want to use an entire address because different operating systems use different paths, obviously.

The best you can do is put your files and requested folders somewhere relative to your program is (whether it's class files or a .jar file).

But with Windows you can be sure that with `System.getProperty("...")` you can retrieve directory URLs as relative paths for your files/folders.

Documentation on System.getProperty here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

I may not have helped or answered your question at all. But hopefully you'll find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this program is for use on an existing (and archaic) file system, so I can't put it in a place which is relevant to my program. I'll probably end up using the System.getProperty solution as you and user Rop suggested. That seems more clean than what I was trying to do.

However, I'm now very curious as to why hard coding it doesn't work, so I'm not going to mark this as the solution unless I don't get a response related to that.